# Can't compile Fortran code

Tags: fortran, fortran77, mingw-w64

I'm very new to Fortran and I'm trying to compile a code written in Fortran 77. It's a simple code but it won't compile on my machine (Windows 7 Home Basic, 64 Bit). I'm using the MinGW Command Prompt and the error message comes up:

```
C:\fortran_project>g77 circle.f -o circle.exe
C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoPxaaa.s: Assembler messages:
C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoPxaaa.s:50: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoPxaaa.s:54: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
etc....
```

Here's the code I tried to compile. It's in Fortran 77

```
    program circle
    real r, area
C This program reads a real number r and prints
C the area of a circle with radius r.
    write (*,*) 'Give radius r:'
    read (*,*) r
    area = 3.14159*r*r
    write (*,*) 'Area = ', area
    stop
    end
```

Why the error? I'm guessing it's because I use a 64bit machine. How do I compile this on my machine and obtain a reasonable output?

Comment: Are you running MinGW for Win64?

Comment: Yes, just set it up: TDM-GCC-64

Comment: i'd say you compiler is not installed properly

Comment: If you are new to Fortran why are you programming like it was 1989 ?  Fortran 90/95/03 would be a better platform in the second decade of the 21st century of the common era.

Comment: Besides FORTRAN 77 being an old language, the compiler g77 is old and unsupported.  I suggest using gfortran ... it can compile Fortran >=90 and FORTRAN 77.   If you have a reason to use FORTRAN 77 (e.g., legacy code), use options `-ffixed-form  -ffixed-line-length-none` with gfortran.

Comment: Why STOP before END? BTW, If you want *true* FORTRAN 77 compatibility you should use capital letters, but I suggest to move to some Fortran version from this century instead.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work using windows 7 (64 bit) and the mingw compiler.

Try:

```
~>gfortran circle.f -o circle.exe
```